# How to interactively update IPywidgets container (VBox, HBox)?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

When I try to update a container that contains other dynamically created container it doesn't change.
I tried different options but in the current one I defined the variables holding the containers before the update function and call this function whenever a change occurs:

```
history_array = []
fig_array = []
history_vbox = widgets.VBox(history_array)
viz_vbox = widgets.VBox(fig_array)
left_box = widgets.HBox([])
gui = widgets.HBox([left_box, viz_vbox])

# updates the gui
def update_gui():
    global gui
    gui = widgets.HBox([left_box, viz_vbox])
    display(gui)
```

later in the script I change the containers globally like:

```
left_box = widgets.VBox([input_box, eq_out0, eqchoice, history_vbox])
```

I tried to display the containers before the function only changed the container without display() and tried many other options but it still only shows an empty list.

I put the notebook on github IpySci.ipynb shows the current state with the describet probelm IpySci-Copy1.ipynb my earliest version that show that the basic function are working as intended.

[github.com/PMK89/IpySci/](https://github.com/PMK89/IpySci/)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the content of HBox/VBox via its `children` property, e.g.:

```
gui.children = [left_box, viz_vbox]
```